# Excel VBA Find/Replace Macro

Tags: excel, replace, vba

Good Morning,

I am working with a rather large dataset and I am attempting to Find/Replace values which have been modified in one spreadsheet back into the original.  What I would like to do is have the macro look for the information in Cell A1 and Replace it with the value in Cell B1, and then continue down until Cell A3600:B3600. Generally, I'm pretty good at peicemealing the code I find on here to get it to do what I want, but I'm at a loss as to what I should be looking for.

What I have right now is:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Range("A1").Select

Selection.Copy
Cells.Replace What:=ActiveCell.Value, Replacement:="????", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

From here I am at a loss.  I understand *Range("A1").Select* will paste into the Find section of the Find/Replace box, but how do I tell excel I want to select another Cell, in this case B1, for the replace portion? And then how do I tell Excel I want it to keep doing this until it runs out of values in the A Column?

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: *"I understand Range("A1").Select will paste into the Find section of the Find/Replace box"* - No it won't. It does nothing other than select a cell.

Comment: Is it just the value in A# that needs the be the value of B# or does B# needs to be replaced with A# aswell?

Comment: Hey T. Nesset.  The values in B#,  3600 unique values, need to replace the values in A#.  Look at my comment below and hopefully that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim OrigStr As String, ReplaceStr As String

Set Rng = Range("A1:B3600")
OrigStr = Range("A1").Value2
ReplaceStr = Range("B1").Value2

' option 1: replace only if the whole cell's string equals to OrigStr
Rng.Replace What:=OrigStr, Replacement:=ReplaceStr, LookAt:=xlWhole

' option 2: replace also partial match inside the cell's string
Rng.Replace What:=OrigStr, Replacement:=ReplaceStr, LookAt:=xlPart

End Sub
```

Comment: Shai, Not quite working.  For instance, in cell A1 and A3 I have "123" and in cell A2 and A4 I have "321".  In cell B1 I have "90123" and in Cell B2 I have "90321".  When I run the code with option  2, Cell A1 and A3 change to what I have I B1, "90123", but there is no change in cell A2 or A4. I need to take this spreadsheet of 3600 numbers in column B2 to Find/Replace data in another sheet that is 30000+ rows.  I'm trying to avoid Find/Replacing manually 3600 times.